# Why am I getting empty CSV after converting XML to CSV?

Tags: python

Using the code below I'm attempting to convert xml files to csv files and then use them with tensorflow for my model training but after converting the file is basically empty with only the headings : 'filename','width', etc. being shown.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def main():
    for folder in ['Train','Test']:
        image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Images/' + folder)
        xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
        xml_df.to_csv(('data/' + folder + '_labels.csv'), index=None)
        print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')

main()
```

and here is and example of what my data looks like

```
<annotation>
    <folder>license</folder>
    <filename>LPTest1.jpg</filename>
    <path>C:\Users\tavon\Desktop\Tensorflow\Workspace\Images\TrainingImages\license\LPTest1.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>600</width>
        <height>799</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>LicensePlate</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>249</xmin>
            <ymin>382</ymin>
            <xmax>353</xmax>
            <ymax>430</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

After running the code it says that the files were created successfully however the files created have no data.

[A screenshot of the final csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ5He.png)

Comment: Have you attempted some debugging. I.e., printing `xml_df`, or printing `xml_list` etc?

Comment: @9769953 Yea I did that last night and realised my list was still empty but I couldn't figured out why but after looking at it with fresh eyes again this morning I printed some variables and paths and realised there was a small issue with the image_path. Thank you

Comment: Does that mean you've solved your problem?